# Best Way to Develop a Composer Package

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have a large project, I'm using git as VCS. Also, I have some modules that I'm able to use in other projects. I want to publish these packages on composer. I'm storing these packages in the `vendor` directory. I'm not pushing the `vendor` directory to VCS.

My problem starts here, Some times I'm developing the project at the same time with the packages. So I need "composer update" etc... but this kind of command may overwrite my development package, or may cause some other problems.

I don't know which is the best way to handle both project and composer packages together.

Comment: I would suggest putting each package into git repositories. Each repo must also contain a composer file describing the package. Now, in your project, you can require the packages and they will automatically appear in your vendor folder, safe and sound

Comment: Do you need to use them in this project or in multiple projects? If in multiple, how do you keep them up to date in all your projects now?

Comment: @Morten I'm doing it like you said, but when do a "composer update" it over writes on my plugin, also it deletes .git files in plugins. Then I need to re set .git settings. This is my exact problem

Comment: Can you explain further the current setup? Or the setup you had when writing the comment? @fobus